# Doctrine2 ODM - [Semantical Error]

Tags: php, doctrine-odm

I keep getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException' with message
>   '[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Document" in class
>   Documents\Translation was never imported.' in
>   /home/bmay/devel/svn/wwv/trunk/test_mongo_record/doctrine-mongodb-odm/lib/vendor/doctrine-mongodb-odm/lib/vendor/doctrine-common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:52

Code is simple here:

```
namespace Documents;

/** @Document */
class Translation
{
    //private $string;
    //private $date;

    /** @String */
    private $name;

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Let me know if more code is needed to diagnose the problem.  Also is Doctrine the right ODM to use, or should I be looking at something else?

Comment: Do I need to load something I'm not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation usage changed in the new versions. Before you can use an annotation, `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations` should be imported with `use`:

```
namespace Documents;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/** @ODM\Document */
class Translation
{
    /** @ODM\String */
    private $name;
}
```

Comment: The above was helpful, but not the whole solution.  I was following the getting started tutorial and it was missing a line: AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses(); Put it just before you create the AnnotationReader object.